# How can I generate an admin link from a frontend controller?

Tags: magento

I would like to have a link from a frontend page to an adminhtml page. I've tried using the Adminhtml helper method:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('some/admin/path')
```

and the Adminhtml URL model method:

```
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('some/admin/path')
```

but to no avail. I just get kicked to the admin dashboard each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you can't (with a few exceptions--see the bottom of this answer), at least not without [disabling admin URL keys](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-disable-remove-secret-key-from-admin-url/)--a security risk.

Magento hashes a session "form key", along with the admin URL path, to generate its admin URL keys. This form key is just a random 16-character string that lasts as long as the session lasts. The trouble is that Magento uses a different session cookie, and hence a different form key, for the frontend and adminhtml areas.

So, when you generate an admin URL from the frontend, Magento uses the form key from the frontend session. Then, when you click that link, Magento regenerates the admin URL key to compare against the key in the link, only this time, it uses the adminhtml form key. Since the form keys don't match, the hashed URL key doesn't match, and your link will not work. Magento's behavior at this point is to kick you back to the admin dashboard (or to the admin login page).

Ultimately, this seems to be a fundamental limitation of Magento. I don't believe there's any workaround for it (but I'd be happy if someone could correct me).

---

Update: Looking into some of Magento's adminhtml controllers, it seems that certain controller actions are excepted from requiring URL keys by default:

- adminhtml/catalog_product/edit
- adminhtml/catalog_product_review/edit
- adminhtml/sales_order/view
- adminhtml/sales_order/index
- All of the Oauth actions.

Any controller that inherits from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` can allow certain actions to not require a admin URL key by adding them to the `$_publicActions` array. So for your own modules, or if you're overriding a Magento module, if you have an `indexAction` in your admin controller that you'd like to be public, you would do so like this:

```
public $_publicActions = array('index');
```

Answer (score 2):

By default you can not, but since this is magento you can always customize it.

Take a look at [Redirection to Admin Customer Edit (with key) from a frontend controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33803/redirection-to-admin-customer-edit-with-key-from-a-frontend-controller)

You can create a admin controller that will act like a proxy to get the url key then redirect to your desire route without disabling admin url key.

You can disable the validation  of admin url using `$_publicActions`).

See `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

```
protected function _validateSecretKey()
{
    if (is_array($this->_publicActions) && in_array($this->getRequest()->getActionName(), $this->_publicActions)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!($secretKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME, null))
        || $secretKey != Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Your proxy controller

```
class MagePal_ProxyCustomerRedirect_Adminhtml_RedirectController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_publicActions = array('redirecttocustomer');

    public function redirecttocustomerAction()
    {
        // get the customer id pass by your observer (url key)
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/customer/edit/", array("id"=>$customer_id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Link to Product Edit page in admin generated in frontend

```
            $urlModel = Mage::getModel('core/url');
            $url = $urlModel->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array(
                '_current' => false,
                'id' => $product->getId()
            ));
```

Comment: have tested on 1.6.2.0 and 1.7.0.2 - works with secret keys too.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry, I was making a false assumption. Interestingly, for me it seems that this only works for product edit pages--every other action I attempted to link to kicked me back to the dashboard. I looked into this a bit and I've now updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use by this example.

```
    Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("module_name/controller_name/action_name",
                                       array("param1"=>1,"param2"=>2));
```

Comment: This will not work for most admin URLs if you have admin URL keys enabled, which is the default configuration and good for security.